# Rally: Parent (recursive) notification

Tags: ruby, notifications, rally

In Rally, we use parent chaining to keep track of user story work items under "Epic" and "Theme" stories.  (not uncommon, I'm sure).  Rally's built-in notification system, while flexible, isn't flexible enough.  If a user changes one story, we get mail bombed when Rally propagates that change across its parent hierarchy.

So, I want to create my own notification process that only notifies users of the item that was directly modified.  From what I can tell so far, Rally doesn't distinguish a propagated update from a direct (user typing at the Rally web client) update.

Does anyone know if there's a programmatic way to detect this?

(note, if this can be figured out, I'll end up using Rally's Ruby framework to code it)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some description of what your notification rules look like? While there may not be a programmatic route, the notification rules are pretty flexible. It's likely that some level of fine-tuning of your rules could greatly reduce the notification spam.

Comment: Yes, more examples, code screens etc

Comment: That should have said - while there may be a programmatic route, maybe there are some additional filters to be tried.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  There's nothing special on my end to show.  Just create a notification rule [like ((Project = My project) AND (Change Author != Me)), which says notify me anytime someone else makes an update].  If you have a story (theme) with a child story (epic) with another child story (user story), then when you make a change to the leaf story (user story), you'll get three email notifications.  I only want to be notified when a human makes a change, not when a auto-propagation robot ripples the change up the tree.

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly write an app using the rally_api Ruby toolkit to query all Stories whose LastUpdateDate meets a certain criterion (probably dictated by the interval at which your integration runs). You could also apply your own various query filters to narrow down your notification result list - including checking the DirectChildrenCount and the Parent fields to see where in the hierarchy the item resides.

From there you could send out notification emails to a list of recipients.

I'd still encourage you to explore fine-tuning your existing notification filters, as building and maintaining a connector like this could be cumbersome, especially if there are a number of users who wish to apply different notification rules.

Comment: The problem is that there isn't a notification filter that says "changed by person" or "changed by auto-propagation".  That's my problem.  Using the tools available (and I suspect the fields available), one cannot distinguish between a direct modification and an automated modification.